# I really need help understanding how to write a class (declaration and definition) just by looking at a main program and sample execution output

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic

I have an example that I've been looking over and I'm trying to figure out how to write the .h and .cpp files by looking at the main file and the output

I have a class called Flex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "flex.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Flex a, b("Merry"), c("Christmas");
    cout << a << ',' << b << ',' << c << endl;
    b.cat(a);
    cout << b << endl;
    b.cat(c);
    cout << b << endl;
    c.cat(c);
    c.cat(c);
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Execution output is:

```
    * *,*Merry*,*Christmas*
    *Merry *
    *Merry Christmas*
    *ChristmasChristmasChristmasChristmas*
```

And then, the declaration/definition files should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Flex
{
   friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& s, const Flex& f);

public:
   Flex();          // default constructor
   Flex(const char *);      // constructor with parameters
   ~Flex();         // destructor (not specifically required)
   void cat(const Flex & f);    // cat function -- concatenation

private:
   char * str;          // variable length string
   int size;
};
```

and

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring>
 #include "flex.h"
 using namespace std;

 ostream& operator<< (ostream& s, const Flex& f)
 {
    s << '*' << f.str << '*';
    return s;
 }

 Flex::Flex()
 {
    size = 1;           // size doesn't include null char
    str = new char[size+1]; // allocate +1 for null char
    strcpy(str," ");
 }

 Flex::Flex(const char * s)
 {
    size = strlen(s);
    str = new char[size+1];
    strcpy(str,s);
 }

 Flex::~Flex()
 // not specifically required by the specs, but a good idea to have this
 {
    delete [] str;
 }

 void Flex::cat(const Flex & f)
 // this function can also be made easier through the use of the
 // strcat library function for concatenating strings.
 // dyanamic reallocation still required, though.
 {
    int newsize = size + strlen(f.str);

    char * temp = new char[newsize+1];  // allocate with room for '\0'
    strcpy(temp,str);           // copy this string to temp
    for (int i = 0; i <= f.size; i++)
        temp[size+i] = f.str[i];    // concatenate f.str to temp,
                        //   including '\0'

    delete [] str;          // delete old array
    str = temp;             // set str to new one
    size = newsize;         // update size tracker
 }
```

This question might be hard to explain, but how does one look at the main program and immediately knows what class he has to write?

I need to do this for a class that involves stats. I do not have a main program yet, but what would we be different since I wouldn't use chars anymore ? 
How would I go about representing a stats class just by looking at a main file and output ?

Comment: I don't reallt see a question here that can be answered. If the question is how experienced developer see a class structure I guess the answers is: we just do...

Answer (score 0):

Operator << sends '`*' << f.str << '*'`(Where f.str it`s your, Flex object, str value ) You have constructor of class Flex

```
Flex::Flex()
{
   size = 1;            // size doesn't include null char
   str = new char[size+1];  // allocate +1 for null char
   strcpy(str," ");
}

Flex::Flex(const char * s)
{
   size = strlen(s);
   str = new char[size+1];
   strcpy(str,s);
}
```

When your initialize object like Flex a("Test"). Your a.str == "Test". When Flex a(), then a.str == "". Function cat is concatanation 2 value. If b.cat(a) it`s mean that b.str = b.str + a.str